# Farewell, Brian!

Tags: discussion, stack-exchange-team, thanks

Thursday we said goodbye to [Brian Nickel](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/235711/brian-nickel), the dev largely responsible for the (sadly, now de-listed) Stack Exchange iOS app... but he's done much more than that in his time here as a valued member of the Public Platform development team.

I discovered the app years ago and it fueled my need to be constantly connected to the sites and to get my notifications when they came in - it was great for a lot of things. I remember writing up bug reports on MSE as some of my earliest actions here and Brian very thoughtfully responded to many of them with a fix relatively quickly, or an explanation of why the behavior is intended.

These were some of my first interactions with a dev here on SE and it was  awesome that he was really interested in listening to issues that the community members had and working to address them - while it's something that I see in many of the devs here now, Brian was always one of the people who stood out from my early days as a user. I appreciate that because it really left me (as a community member) feeling like my efforts to help improve the site were valued.

From working here with him, I've come to know him as a very thoughtful, caring person who listens and is able to understand the needs of a project even when they aren't expressly stated. He's able to ask questions and devise solutions that are creative and clean. He's also well-recognized as being an excellent reviewer for code going out; able to see room for improvement and catch potential bugs that others may have overlooked.

It was great to work with him on projects like digging into the chat code to  [redesign the Teachers' Lounge](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/357905/new-chat-moderation-tools-for-the-teachers-lounge), so that it could be moderated and his role as lead engineer on the [Review Queues project](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/346901/improving-the-review-queues-project-overview) from the beginning - these changes have really been beneficial for reviewers.

Thank you for your time and efforts - you will be missed! We wish you well in your next adventure!

Answer (score 17):

While I'm not the one fairwelling - Bilbo's speech in Lord of the Rings comes to mind

> "I don't know half of you half as well as I should like, and I like less than half of you half as well as you deserve."

And I think Brian very much fits in the first category.

The TL moderation changes are something I personally notice and appreciate, and I think many of the things Brian's worked on have touched all our experiences on SE.

Good luck on your next adventure :)

Answer (score 10):

I'll share several chat messages I've posted about Brian over the years.

- [October 19<sup>th</sup>, 2015](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/89?m=4090025#4090025)

  > Brian is doing excellent work and fixing tons of stuff, on the other hand, they'll probably close the app if and when he decides to move on from SE. :D
- [December 30<sup>th</sup>, 2015](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/89?m=4388616#4388616)

  > And this Brian is a demon, fixing bugs like crazy and adding cool features.
- [July 20<sup>th</sup>, 2017](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/89?m=6200479#6200479)

  > @Brian is the fastest dev I've ever seen, but still...

I stand behind each and any of those, and more. Double each, triple each, and you still won't reach the level of appreciation I have to this wonderful man.

So, thank you Brian, and thank you for all the wonderful things you left behind you! :)

Answer (score 8):

> Life will continue on forever 
>  But people who like you will leave and go 
>  I don't know how to react then 
>  life becomes so slow 
>  So farewell my friend to you 
>  As I bid you a final goodbye

Thanks [Brian](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/235711/brian-nickel) for making the iOS app functionality better and for fixing the bugs. You will always be in our hearts. Bye for the last time.