# Regular moderators can still purge the history of messages in moderated private rooms

Tags: bug, status-completed, chat, moderator-tools, teachers-lounge

The [Teachers' Lounge](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/teachers-lounge/info) is a "moderated private room", in which regular moderators like me have [limited powers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/357905/295232):

> They won't be able to
>
> ...
>
> - purge the history of messages

I can see that the option to go to the history of a chat message is hidden from the UI, but I still have [access to that page](https://chat.stackexchange.com/messages/60753952/history), it had the familiar orange 'Purge history' button and after clicking it, the history seems to be gone:

> #### Message history
>
> (no history available)

Comment: Hope that message wasn't important! :)

Comment: The message is still there, it just doesn't have a history anymore.

Comment: Oh, I see. My experience seeing chat message purges was limited to an instance where the message was deleted and-also had its history purged.

Comment: Yes, that is the most common use case.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Thanks for the report!

This was fixed a few days ago - going forward, only CMs and moderators who were assigned the full moderation privileges in the TL will be able to purge message history.