# Special characters in moderators' names break formatting in 'whois' response

Tags: bug, status-review, chat, markdown, teachers-lounge

The [Teachers' Lounge](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/357905/295232) has a chatbot with a `whois` function listing moderators for a specific site. The response is in italics, but it's a Markdown message, and moderator names with an underscore at the end like ['ow_'](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/users/23305/ow) cause the formatting to break:

[image: a transcript example of the bot's feeback]

Here is the Markdown equivalent of both messages, which is hopefully clear enough to indicate why this bug happens:

> *I'm aware of 2 moderators on opendata.stackexchange.com: Nicolas Raoul, Pluviophile. None of them are currently in this room.*

---

> *I’m aware of 3 moderators on datascience.stackexchange.com: oW*, Stephen Rauch, Ben Reiniger. None of them are currently in this room._

When moderators *are* present in the room, their name is bolded with double asterisks, which could cause additional formatting problems, but I haven't investigated that in detail.

Comment: Asterisks also give italics. Are asterisks allowed in usernames? If not, the fix could be as simple as re-coding the bot to post the message `*like this*` instead of `_like this_`.

Comment: One way to fix it is to just have it put a line break in the message, so the message renders as plain text.

Comment: @Randal'Thor you asked for it; I'm going to try to append an asterisk to your username </jk>

Comment: Did a bit of testing in regular chat - a slightly cludgy solution might be to 'seperately' wrap the user names in formatting.  - chat markdown only reads the 'outer' markdown formats - so having the fixed parts of the string wrapped in underscores and the usernames 'seperately' in underscores might help