# Why did the diamond become a square?

Tags: bug, design, moderators

I was reading [a question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/382902/special-characters-in-moderators-names-break-formatting-in-whois-response), on mobile, when I noticed the following in the comments:

[image]

Glorfindel's diamond had become a square. Scrolling down a bit further turned it into a diamond again, but scrolling back up turned it into a square once more.

Using Google Chrome on a Huawei P20 pro.

**Edit:** I can reproduce this on any question where a moderator is outside the original viewport of the screen. In comments, as well as in post usercards when there is a longer post. It appears the rendering is off in some way, as it gradually transitions from square to diamond line by line pixelwise.

[image]

**Also replicated on the main question page:**
[image]

Comment: No repro in Firefox 105.2.0 Android 12.

Comment: No repro in Chrome 106.0.5249.79, Android 12

Comment: I have a screenshot showing half a diamond and half a square, but unable to upload right now.

Comment: I've seen this happen if the page doesn't load completely.

Comment: Well that small diamond is actually some complex inline SVG, so it's natural that older or slower browsers will take time or have trouble to render it. :/

Comment: I was able to reproduce this by manually removing the CSS. [Screenshot](https://i.imgur.com/B9TAYOt.png). So it means that in any slow connection it can happen, until the CSS is rendered, not only on a mobile device.

Comment: @ShadowTheKidWizard I think the origin here is different, as I can continue reproducing it on the same page. When I go back up it reverts from a diamond to a square, when I go down again it turns to a square once more. This happens gradually, as deminstrated by the screenshot I just added.

Comment: Glorfindel's [not square](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CP9pA.png), or a repro.

Comment: @Rob for me the transition occurs at about one post owner banner height from the bottom of the screen

Comment: Luuk, using Shadow's URL for the .SVG code, I loaded it into an online editor: https://yqnn.github.io/svg-path-editor/ and I see the expected icon: https://i.stack.imgur.com/clp1y.png

Comment: I can also reproduce this in Chrome on a Pixel 3. Though I'm not quite sure what we could do about it. The SVG is perfectly fine. It feels like Chrome is trying to de-render things that are off-screen for performance savings but not getting the "is this off-screen" check quite right. I can't test this right now, but I'm curious if the same icon on a long blank page would exhibit the same behavior.

Comment: From a little more playing with it, this seems to only happen to me if you are scrolling while the address bar in Chrome has been hidden, and the icon starts rendering the same number of pixels up as the address bar would have taken. If I'm scrolling up while the address bar is fully visible, no rendering issue ever occurs. This looks like a bug with Chrome.

Comment: That seems exactly the case @animuson. Perhaps there is something that could be done on SE sid, but other than that its just waiting on Google.

Comment: More follow-up: this is not specific to the diamond icon. I just had this happen with the "watched tag" icon while scrolling a question list and also the trash icon for deleted questions later. So it affects all SVGs and is definitely on Chrome's side. I highly doubt there's anything we could do to fix it ourselves.