# Room moderators should be able to edit the room description and manage lower levels of access

Tags: feature-request, chat, moderator-tools, teachers-lounge

Some private chatrooms, most notably the Teachers' Lounge (the network-wide moderator chatroom), are a special type of private room — a staff-moderated room with appointed "room moderators".
In these "hollow diamond" rooms, regular moderators do not have access to their moderator tools (except for being able to edit your own messages past the time limit). However, room moderators (note that this is a distinct and separate role from room *owners*) do have access to most moderator tools in that room and are responsible for handling any flags, maintaining the starboard, and anything else that might need diamond powers.

However, there are a couple things that room moderators do *not* currently have access to that I believe they should; editing the room description, and managing lower-level access permissions.

For instance, if I want to swap out a link in the room description, I would need to flag down a staff member and request that they edit the description, meaning staff needs to get involved instead of the room moderator just being able to take care of it. If somebody clicks "request access" to the room, the request will just sit there until staff clears it. Sometimes access requests are an indicator that something's funky with a mod's chat access, which any moderator can handle, but if nobody's monitoring and clearing those requests those signals can get lost.

To sum up: Can room moderators please be given the necessary permissions for editing the room description and maintaining access for lower-level room roles?

Comment: @Sonic unless that room moderator privilege is specific to the TL, the tag is invalid here as it was given only as example. If you have reference proving it's just there and not for every private room, please link to it. If not, the tag should be removed, and [tag:private-chat-room] should be used instead. (Can't test it myself and OP also can't respond until tomorrow.)

Comment: @ShadowWizardLoveZelda The [original announcement of the feature](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/357905/new-chat-moderation-tools-for-the-teachers-lounge) says it's specific to the TL. Also, looking at other uses of the tag I added, many of its uses are about the moderator private room functionality. Finally, even if there are other rooms that are "moderated private rooms", it doesn't mean it's an invalid application of the tag - any bugs affecting those rooms also, by token, affect the TL. I have pinged the author in chat asking if there are other such rooms but they haven't replied

Comment: See also [this revision history](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/377516/revisions), where a then-staff member edited out the [tag:private-chat-room] tag and replaced it with [tag:teachers-lounge]. Most likely they needed to choose one tag or the other due to the tag limit (they were also adding a status tag), but they clearly felt that the latter tag was more important and so changed it instead of leaving it alone.

Comment: @Sonic fair, I won't dig into it further, but still wonder if it applies to any, or other, private chat. Mith can probably reply later.